# Formtastic number field with decimal precision?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

Surely I'm missing something pretty obvious... I have a field that is decimal with precision 2, but Formtastic is displaying it with only a single decimal, unless the actual value has 2 places. What am I missing?

Model:

```
create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "item_number"
    t.integer  "buyer_id"
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.string   "description"
    t.decimal  "sales_price", :precision => 10, :scale => 2, :default => 0.0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

View

```
%td= bought.input :sales_price, input_html: { class: 'span2'}, label: false
```

Noting answer from below, which might not be clear to others finding this later:

```
%td= bought.input :sales_price, input_html: { class: 'span2', value: number_with_precision(bought.object.sales_price, precision: 2)}, label: false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
%td= bought.input :sales_price, input_html: { class: 'span2', value: number_with_precision(bought.sales_price, precision: 2) }, label: false
```

Sales_price is being stored in your database with two decimal places, but you have to tell rails to format it that way when displaying the value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I neglected to mention that `bought` is a nested attribute. When trying your solution, I get an error that `sales_price` is an undefined method. Do I need to reference it differently?

Comment: Ah, found the answer ... same as above, but adding 'object':

value: number_with_precision(bought.object.sales_price, precision: 2)

Answer (score 1):

## Modify StringInput

@xnm's answer was helpful to me, but doing this on each input would be tedious, so I took it a step further to solve this problem application-wide.

I did this by modifying the behavior of regular input fields, which Formtastic calls `StringInput`, by creating my own version, as shown in in the [Formtastic README](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).

The code below is for for DataMapper models, so that anytime a property is declared as `Decimal`, the input will show the correct number of decimal places. This approach could be modified for other ORMs.

```
# app/inputs/string_input.rb

# Modified version of normal Formtastic form inputs.
# When creating an input field for a DataMapper model property, see if it is
# of type Decimal. If so, display the value with the number of decimals
# specified on the model.
class StringInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def to_html
    dm_property = @object.class.properties.detect do |property| 
      property.name == @method
    end rescue nil

    if dm_property && dm_property.class == DataMapper::Property::Decimal
      @options[:input_html] ||= {}
      @options[:input_html][:value] ||= @template.number_with_precision(

        # What DataMapper calls "scale" (number of digits right of the decimal),
        # this helper calls "precision"
        @object.send(@method), precision: dm_property.options[:scale]
      )
    end

    super
  end
end
```

Comment: A very nice solution. I'll have to try that on my next project.